# How does Overlapped I/O relates to the concept of blocking and non-blocking sockets?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, network-programming, overlapped-io

I am wondering does using Overlapped I/O means that I am using the socket in a non-blocking mode, or does the concept of blocking and non-blocking sockets is not related to the concept of Overlapped I/O.

Comment: With overlapped I/O, you don't have to directly interact much with the socket.  You queue I/O requests and buffers to the kernel/stack and wait for completion notification.  It's a bit like select/epoll, but does not require send/recv calls from user state - the buffer sending/loading can be handled inside kernel state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say they are not related to one another. Blocking vs. Non-Blocking for sockets is straight forward. If you're calling `send()` or `recv()` in non-blocking mode and the socket doesn't have anything available (no outbound buffer space for `send()`, no inbound data for `recv()`), you receive an error response of `WSAWOULDBLOCK`. If in blocking mode, the function will simply not return until the requested operation has completed or an error has occurred.

However, I/O overlapping is more of a delegate pattern. It will accept your `WSASend()` or `WSARecv()` request and handle it for you. However, this isn't going to be as soon as the function returns. Instead these functions receive a pointer to a callback that the client specifies. Once the send/recv operation is completed, you are notified via the callback method you provided.

I would say I/O Overlapping is to remove the need for client programmers to continuously check non-blocking sockets and calling `select()` to poll them.